# Does the Apache 2.0 license require attribution on a commercial work on which it is based?

Tags: licensing, open-source-software

I'm using [Nativescript](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/LICENSE) which is licensed under the Apache 2.0 license.

Provided that I do not intend to change Nativescript itseft, but I'm using it to develop an application, am I expected to give attribution to the license and/or Nativescript in the final app that I deliver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you are.

You still need to keep the LICENSE and NOTICE files in the repository, if there were any in your copy of the project. These files contain the terms and conditions for the project, and provide attribution to the original developers. If you're trying to attribute in the UI of your application, you probably should. It's considered courteous and in the spirit of open source as well. This is also related: [Do I need to include the full text of the MIT license in the UI of my app?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6466/do-i-need-to-include-the-full-text-of-the-mit-license-in-the-ui-of-my-app/6501#6501)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to make sure I got it right:
- the repository is private so in theory no attribution is needed. right?
- in the app I can add a quick reference to Nativescript in the app in a "about" section. right?

Comment: @dragonmnl If the project is in the repository of your application, then all you really need to make sure is that the LICENSE and NOTICE files of the projects are there, and you're pretty much set. If you're just using it internally, it's not that much of a big deal anyway.